# Inputing a String into MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am trying to get ask the user to input data in to perform the insert, it works whenever I have numbers, but when I input letters it gives me the error "LettersUsed" is not defined. I tried converting the input to str(input('Whatever')) but that did not do the trick any help why it does this?

```
import pymongo
import sys

#get a connection to database
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost')
    #get a handle to database
db=connection.test
vehicles=db.vehicles

vehicle_VIN = input('What is the Vehicle VIN number? ')
vehicle_Make = input('What is the Vehicle Make? ')
newVehicle = {'VIN' : (vehicle_VIN).upper(), 'Make' : (vehicle_Make)}

try:
    vehicles.insert_one(newVehicle)
    print ('New Vehicle Inserted')

except  Exception as e:
        print 'Unexpected error:', type(e), e

#print Results
results = vehicles.find()

print()
# display documents in collection
for record in results:
    print(record['VIN'] + ',',record['Make'])
#close the connection to MongoDB
connection.close()
```

Comment: You are showing us the wrong code. Your error is with variable `LettersUsed` not defined when you attempt to use it, and yet the code shown doesn't use this variable at all.

Comment: I didn't quote know how to word it but basically I type into the input something and I use letters it throws me an error "Whatever Letter I used" say I used FJ3132D it would be NameError: name 'FJ3132D is not defined or if i used 3JDAD it would be NameError: name '3JDAD' is not defined. I'm am just trying insert the string into the document. Does this clarify?

Comment: Your code run perfectly here if you replace `print 'Unexpected error:', type(e), e` with `print('Unexpected error:', type(e), e)` and fix the indentation of that line. Can you post the entire stack trace error.

Comment: When I used '1B3B3F' for vehicle_VIN                              exceptions.SyntaxError occurred
Message: unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)                               When I use DAFEQF for vehicle_VIN                    exceptions.NameError occurred
Message: name 'DAFEQF' is not defined

Comment: That error means there is a syntax error with your code. Python can't even run your code, because it cannot even parse it. I will post a correctly formatted version as an answer that you can copy + paste.

Comment: Ok thank you, MongoDB is so hard for me to learn =/

Answer (score 0):

> Message: name 'DAFEQF' is not defined

In Python 2 the code `input()` is equal to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. This means that whatever input you enter, Python2 tries to "evaluate" that input, and will complain that your input is not defined.

Make sure you replace `input()` with `raw_input()` (this is only for Python2!)

Replace

```
vehicle_VIN = input('What is the Vehicle VIN number? ')
vehicle_Make = input('What is the Vehicle Make? ')
```

with

```
vehicle_VIN = raw_input('What is the Vehicle VIN number? ')
vehicle_Make = raw_input('What is the Vehicle Make? ')
```

Comment: I tried it in a new project and I get the same error when I try to enter a vehicle_VIN with any letters in it.

Comment: OK I see your issue now. You are running in Python2, but have Python3 code. I've updated the answer - you need to replace `input(..)` with `raw_input(...)`